# Replace SATA controller without re-installing Windows

Tags: windows-7, sata

I have a machine which just had a motherboard and processor upgrade. The new MB has onboard SATA and so I don't need the PCI SATA controller. Only problem is windows will try boot and fail since it has the wrong drivers.

In the past I just re-install but I don't feel like it on this machine.

OS is Windows 7 - it can't recover on its own ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the PCI card, boot the machine with the drive(s) attached to the card, install the new drivers for the on-board controller, shut down and remove the card. The machine should then boot normally. You may need to change settings in the BIOS to allow it to boot from the PCI card.

Comment: Beat me to it...

Comment: I owe you beer :) kinda "duh" when you think about it, anyway - worked like a charm ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the new controller while old hardware is still together.  Then run sysprep.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/07cacaf8-f14f-47cd-aa68-f4a22185ca1f

Of course if the new box is together, you should be able to boot to windows with the PCI SATA controller, then install all drivers and sysprep.

Answer (score 0):

just boot using the Windows CD/DVD(whatever) then use the rescue/repair mode to correct any boot problem with the new controller.